# How should i create the index of files using boto and S3 using python django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I have the folder structure with 2000 files on S3.
I want that every week i run the program that gets the lists of files are folders from s3 and populates the database.

Then i use that database to show same folder structure on the site.

I ahve two problems

How can i get the list of folders from there and then store them in mysql. Do i need to grab all the file names and then split with "/" . But it looks diffuclt to see which files belong to which folders. I have found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/17096755/1958218 but could not found where is `listObjects()` function

Answer (score 0):

doesn't get_all_keys() method of the s3 bucket do what you need:

```
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
b = s3.get_bucket('bucketname')
keys = b.get_all_keys()
```

then iterate over keys, do os.path.split and unique...